# VLC proxy settings and .pac file

Tags: proxy, vlc-media-player, last.fm

I'm behind a corporate proxy and i want to use the last.fm autoscrobbler in vlc.

Our proxy configuration are in a .pac file and i can't figure out how to set it in vlc's settings...

i tried to fill the http proxy field with

```
http://domain\username@[proxy ip]:8181/proxy.pac
```

but nothing seems working.

what's the trick?

or, is there any trick?

Comment: So you Proxy.pac is on an http://ipaddress:port/proxy.pac what happens if you try to VLC authenticate automatically without the username bit? It should use your windows credentials

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK vlc doesn't support PAC files.  Download and look at the pack file with a text editor.   You should be able to figure out the actual proxy that is being configured.  Then simply configure VLC to use that.